# How detects parent form for Control?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey-fm3

Need to detect the Parent Form in Delphi (FireMonkey 3) for any Control on this form.

What is the easiest way for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Root`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Root) property of a control points to the uppermost Parent.

Root is of interface type [`IRoot`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Types.IRoot). Calling `GetObject` on it results in the Form. The Form can be of type `TCustomForm`, `TCustomForm3D`, `TForm`, `TForm3D`, all which have [`TCommonCustomForm`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm) as ancestor:

```
function GetParentForm(Control: TFmxObject): TCommonCustomForm;
begin
  if (Control.Root <> nil) and
      (Control.Root.GetObject is TCommonCustomForm) then
    Result := TCommonCustomForm(Control.Root.GetObject)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```